¿Como arreglar error: unable to verify the first certificate al Instalar CLI para Angular?
Estoy intentando instalar CLI para angular con Node v16.20.0 (LTS)
  npm: '8.19.4',
  node: '16.20.0',
  v8: '9.4.146.26-node.26',
  uv: '1.43.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.19.0',
  modules: '93',
  nghttp2: '1.47.0',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.10',
  openssl: '1.1.1t+quic',
  cldr: '41.0',
  icu: '71.1',
  tz: '2022f',
  unicode: '14.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.8.1',
  nghttp3: '0.7.0'

Cuando uso el comenado npm install -g @angular/cli
Tengo los siguientes errores.
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\juan.cordova\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-23T13_09_39_164Z-debug-0.log*

y el log tiene esto:
47 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
47 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
47 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
47 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
47 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
47 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
47 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
47 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
48 verbose cwd C:\Users\juan.cordova
49 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
50 verbose node v16.20.0
51 verbose npm  v8.19.4
52 error code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
53 error errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
54 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
55 verbose exit 1

Intente varias cosa como desinstalar todo y volver a instalar o eliminar todos los archivos de raíz o instalar una versión especifica de angular, pero sigue dando el mismo error incluso probé con otra versión de node

Intentaste con esto?
Usa el comando:
npm config set strict-ssl false

Este comando deshabilita los certificados SSL. Pero no es una buena práctica aceptar un certificado SSL no válido. puedes revertirlo más tarde con este comando
npm config set strict-ssl true


Funciono, muchas gracias
